# Set initial value fro Vuetify autocomplete with server site search

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using a `v-autocomplete` component to search for places on the google api. So the `items` array gets filled after the search input is set. Now I'm trying to set a default value to be searched before the user makes an input to suggest a train station.

E.g. the search is opened for the city *London*, now I wan't to set the search input to *London Train Station* so the user sees the results for that search. However, when I set the search input to a default value it get's reset to null every time.

Here is my template:

```html
    <v-autocomplete
      ref="trainStationSearch"
      v-model="select"
      :items="places"
      :search-input.sync="searchTerm"
      no-filter
      return-object
    >
      <template #item="data">
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>{{ data.item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          <v-list-item-subtitle>{{ data.item.subtitle }}</v-list-item-subtitle>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </template>
    </v-autocomplete>
```

And here the logic:

- I have a watcher on `searchTerm`, which triggers a debounced search with Lodash's `debounce` function
- I try to set `searchTerm` in the `mounted` hook with the value of the prop `prefill`

  - Doing it with the timeout triggers the watcher on `searchTerm` and shows the value of `prefill` on the input of the `v-autocomplete` component. Shortly after `searchTerm` is reset to `null`
  - Doing it without a timeout results in `searchTerm` being set to `null` immediately

```js
  @Prop() readonly prefill?: string

  private places: any = []
  private searchTerm: string | null = ''
  private select: any = null

  private searchGoogle = _.debounce(
    async (val: string, context: Vue): Promise<void> => {
      if (val) {
        // doing the request to my API, which returns the google results
        const data = await apiManager.searchPlaces(val)
        // set the items array to the google results
        this.$set(context, 'places', data.predictions)
      }
    },
    1000
  )

  @Watch('searchTerm')
  private searchPlaces(val: string): void {
    if (val?.trim().length > 0) {
      // trigger debounced request
      this.searchGoogle(val, this)
    } else {
      // empty places array
      this.places.splice(0, this.places.length)
    }
  }

  @Watch('select')
  private handleSelection(): void {
    if (!this.select) {
      return
    }

    // handle selection
  }

  private mounted() {
    if (this.prefill) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.searchTerm = this.prefill!
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone to the official vuetify discord to get an answer to this and found out that resetting the search-input with my given conditions is just the intended behaviour. With that in mind I tried to figure out what is the difference between setting the search-input programmatically and manually typing in the text field to mutate the search-input. It's the focus of the text field.

So the workaround for me was to call `focus()` on the autocomplete element before setting the `searchTerm`